# How to deblur an image in frequency domain in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

I've blurred an image by using averaging filter mask in frequency domain. Now, I want to deblur it but I keep getting a black image. Here is my code:

*1161x799 is the size of my image

I want to know why I keep getting a black image even if I use another trustworthy code.

```
im_gray = rgb2gray(im);
im_gray = im2double(im_gray);
%17*17 Average Filter
avgFilter = ones(17) / 289;
%Now taking FFT of both image and filter to work in frequency domain
im_fft = fft2(im_gray, 1161,799);
avgFilter_fft = fft2(avgFilter, 1161,799);
Conv = im_fft .* avgFilter_fft;
%inverse FFT
blurry_image = ifft2(Conv);
%deblur
Inv = Conv./avgFilter_fft; 
deblur = ifft2(Inv);
```

Comment: what are the max and min values of the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely computing 0/0 for some frequency component, meaning `Inv` will have a NaN value, meaning that `deblur` is all NaN. Make sure to avoid the division by zero:

```
Inv = Conv ./ (avgFilter_fft + 1e-12);
```

Alternatively, fix the result of the division by removing NaN values:

```
Inv = Conv ./ avgFilter_fft;
Inv(isnan(Inv)) = 0;
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much.